# Вывод результата побитовой операции в Bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Хочу реализовать простейший пример. Есть два числа в двоичной системе `0011` и `0101`. Хочу применить к ним операцию "ПОБИТОВОЕ ИЛИ". Результат вывести в виде двоичного числа. Должно получиться `0111`, получаю 73.
Почему так?

```
#!/bin/bash
AA=0011
BB=0101
CC=$(($AA | $BB))
echo "Result: " $CC
```

Comment: во первых результат выводится в десятичной, во вторых входные числа воспринимаются как восьмеричные так как начинаются с нуля. Я бы предложил воспользоваться `bc`

Comment: Как поправить так, чтобы все было в двоичной системе?. Если не сложно, покажите, как сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Двоичные числа в bash задаются как `2#число`. Выводить в двоичном виде результат bash не умеет, можно воспользоваться `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
AA=2#0011
BB=2#0101
CC=$(($AA | $BB))
echo -n "Result: "
printf "%04d" `echo "obase=2;$CC" | bc`
```

Comment: Да, все нормально. Есть только одно "но" - как сделать так, чтобы ведущие нули не отбрасывались? Выводится "111", а должно "0111"...
Мне для анализа нужны все биты.....

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov Пока в голову пришел грязный хак через printf в десятичной системе. Баракин придет, наверняка красивее и короче сделает. От себя замечу, что может стоит использовать что нибудь более приспособленное для работы с битами, например `perl`

Comment: Да я бы тогда на Python сделал. Просто не хочется плодить сущности сверх необходимого... Надо реализовать мониторинг загруженности нескольких GPU, все прочие необходимые скрипты сделал на Bash, осталось только это. Самый просто способ - через двоичное число, где каждому биту соответствует свое GPU и его статус - 1 (все хорошо) и 0 (все плохо). А потом периодически накладывать на это предыдущее значение.... И если два раза подряд одному и тому же GPU плохо, то сообщить об этом.

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov Если нужны нули, и вы знаете сколько и не брезгуете перлом, то `perl -e "printf \"%08b\n\", $((2#0011 | 2#0100))"`.

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov вот и делайте! Единственное, у питона тоже всё плохо с битами (там надо городить или свой класс, или использовать чьи-то варианты, не всегда гибкие).

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov на Питоне: `print("{:04b}".format(0b0011 | 0b0101))` -> `0111`

Comment: А на чем тогда делать, чтобы все хорошо с битами было? Perl?

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov На самом деле многие языки подойдут, вот вам jfs питоновский короткий вариант предложил. perl чем то выдающимся с битами не отличается, примерно то же самое как в питоне, только с более C-ным синтаксисом. perl way в вашей задаче думаю был бы массив с состояниями

Answer (score 3):

Выводить в двоичном виде bash не умеет, но можно как-то так (без bc):

```
BA=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
AA=2#0011
BB=2#0101
CC=${BA[$((AA|BB))]}
echo $CC
```